# How to combine multi-level column annotation in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I currently have this heatmap looking like this below
[image]

I want to modify several things:

1. Combine every 2 top-most column annotation instead of being duplicated like the image above.
2. Add border between 'H' and 'T1D' (or alternatively change the background color of 'H' and 'T1D' to 2 different colors)
3. Add outer border to every 2 columns

[image: Details]

So far, I have managed to add horizontal spacing for every 2 columns by using 'grid' package according to this [page](https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/18565299.html). The rest are done purely using ggplot2. Feel free to add another package if necessary.

Here is the [sample data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l4_xekCInzoEYSBu4O63WU32He2LWH9G/view?usp=sharing) where you can sort of recreate this heatmap. The data consist of 5 columns (i.e. CELL.TYPE, SAMPLE, GENE, VAL, COND). The x-axis of the heatmap should be the sample, and the y-axis is the gene, but we have to do this for every different cell type (CELL.TYPE) and condition (COND).

Comment: Seems like most of your problems would be solved more easily if you used a single facet column per pair instead of one. You could just offset your T1D sample by the maximum x-value of the H sample, and manually add text at the top. As far as I know, most of your requests can't be accommodated by vanilla ggplot2.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I couldn't understand the meaning of single facet column per pair, and also maximum x-value. Do you mind to make a few lines of code or something to elaborate on that? Thanks a lot

Comment: I could maybe try if you'd make a reproducible example that catches the problem areas of the plot.

Comment: @teunbrand I will edit my post soon with small dataset for you to try on. Thanks

Comment: @teunbrand I have included a small sample data for you to play with :)